# is there any api refrence or documentation for Houzz integration?

Tags: channel, marketplace

I'm looking for the api doc for Houzz marketplace or Channel , but so far I didn't find any link or doc officially . Can anybody help me how to find link of the same topic or call REST API's of Houzz marketplace. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Houzz doesn't provide the Public Api documentation like Amazon, Bigcommerce,Shopify etc. You not find full documentation anywhere on google. Houzz allows the doc only for sellers. So if you want the API doc , create a sellers account on Houzz. and then navigate to Sellers page then you'll get the API pdf.